# Indefinite integral of expression including DiracDelta function doesn't work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here is the simplified code:

```
e[t_]:=DiracDelta[t] Exp[-I omegaC t]
R[t1_] := Exp[-I omega21 t1]
Integrate[R[t1]*e[t- t1], t1,Assumptions -> {t1 >= 0, t >= t1}]
```

It doesn't calculate, just return the input.
I don't know why, the integrated expression is simple.

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: OK, I will. ${}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workround:

```
e[t_] := DiracDelta[t]*Exp[-I*omegaC*t]
R[t1_] := Exp[-I*omega21*t1]
{a, b} = ReIm[R[t1]*e[t - t1]] // ComplexExpand
sol = Integrate[{a, b}, t1, Assumptions -> {t1 >= 0, t >= t1}]
sol[[1]] + sol[[2]]*I // TrigToExp // FullSimplify

(* E^(-I omega21 t) HeavisideTheta[-t + t1] *)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well and maybe I've already known where I'm wrong.

Comment: Nicely done with splitting into components! (IOU one upvote.)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. Why MMA can't solve? I tried Maple and give me correct answer.

Comment: I guess this is worth reporting to support...

Comment: This solution turns to be robust, it still works elegantly when things become complicated, for example, more than one variables.

Comment: @Bettertomo .Thanks. I'm send a  e-mail  to support(WRI) with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Simplifying a bit your integrand, and assuming that $t, omegaC, t1,a ,b$ and $omega21$ are Reals:

```
Assuming[t >= t1 && a > 0 && b >= 0 && omegaC \[Element] Reals && 
omega21 \[Element] Reals, 
Exp[-I omegaC t] Integrate[ComplexExpand@(E^(-I (omegaC (-t1) + omega21 t1))) 
DiracDelta[t - t1], t1, Assumptions -> True]] // FullSimplify
```

and it yields:

```
E^(-I omega21 t) HeavisideTheta[-t+t1]
```

Comment: I saw an error, and edited it in my solution. It agrees with that  of Mariusz, voting up !

Comment: Sorry to edit it wrongly a moment ago, it is what I want!

Comment: Note that this gives the same result:  `Integrate[R[t1]*e[t - t1] // ComplexExpand, t1, 
  Assumptions -> {t1 >= 0, t >= t1}] // FullSimplify`.  It doesn't appear to be necessary to assume any of the other constants are real.

Answer (score 3):

If you change your integral slightly you get what you're looking for:

```
Integrate[R[t1]*e[t - t1], {t1, low, high}, Assumptions -> {low < t < high}]
(* E^(-I omega21 t) *)
```

Comment: But $t\geq t1$ isn`t it?

Comment: @evanb, thanks, it works except that it can not include the assumption "t>t1".